# mutual information of coupled variables

Tags: information-theory

I have been looking for a method for evaluating the mutual information between a combination of source variables, $X_0, X_1$ and a target variable, $Y$.

$$I(Y;X_0,X_1)$$

When I look on [wikipedia's article about multivariate mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information), they seem to be solving a problem that is more complicated than what I am working on, in that they appear to be keeping the variables separate, and are looking at the various relationships between $X_0,X_1$ and $Y$.

I just want to think of $X_0,X_1$ as a single variable, call it $A$, and calculate:

$$I(Y;A)$$

...but I don't know how to do this.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, you don't need to bother with the "multivariate mutual information" you link -that's a rather esoteric and dubious extension of the proper mutual information.

You need nothing special, just the usual [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Definition_of_mutual_information) of $I(Y;X)$. That $X=(X_0,X_1)$ is a multivariate variable does not really change anything:

$$I(Y;X_0,X_1) = \sum_{X_0,X_1,Y} p(X_0,X_1,Y) \log \frac{p(X_0,X_1,Y)}{p(Y)p(X_0,X_1)}$$
or any of the equivalent defintions using conditional entropies.

For example, among many possible expressions, using $I(Y;X)=H(X)-H(X|Y)$ :

$$\begin{array}[rl]\\
I(Y;X_0,X_1) &= H(X_0,X_1) - H(X_0,X_1|Y)\\
&=H(X_0)+H(X_1|X_0)-H(X_0|Y) -H(X_1|X_0,Y)\end{array}$$

Comment: Great, that's just what I needed, Thank you. Is there a conceptual way of thinking about this that would have enabled me to see that it is allowed to apply this to a "multivariate variable", without having to ask?

Comment: A multivariate random variable is a random variable. Most fundamental formulas in information theory -and in probability- that deal with a random variable $X$ do _not_ assume or require that $X$ is a "scalar" (say, real valued). When we speak, for example, of $p(X)$ (the probability density function), $X$ can well be a vector, in which case it's implicitly assume that we are speaking of a joint density; and so on.

Comment: Of course. I see it now. Many thanks. When I get more reputation I will also upvote your answer :)