# what is the mutual information of three variables?

Tags: information-theory

mutual information of tow variables is
  $\displaystyle\sum\sum p(x,y)\ln\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}$
what is the mutual information of three variables?
is it
$\displaystyle\sum\sum\sum p(x,y,z)\ln\frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(x)p(y)p(z)}$?

Comment: $\sum\sum\ln\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}$ is always positive, can you show the same for a "3-way mutual information"? What would it mean if it could be defined?

Comment: I don't know, i have a question and i need someone to guide me

Comment: The mutual information $I(X;Y)$ relates two random variables. This concept is not readily extensible to more variables; it could be done, but it is not very nice/consistent/useful/used. Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890045/mutual-information-of-coupled-variables

Comment: For the record, the given equation is the definition of [total correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_correlation)

Answer (score 11):

That's a good guess, but the mutual information of three variables is (following the notations used in the question)
$$I(X;Y;Z)=\sum_x\sum_y\sum_z p(x,y,z)\ln\frac{p(x,y)p(x,z)p(y,z)}{p(x,y,z)p(x)p(y)p(z)}$$
With the natural logarithm, this would be in [**nat**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_%28unit%29)s, of course.  This is in accord with the definition $I(X;Y;Z)=I(X;Y)-I(X,Y|Z)$.  For more than three variables, the expression is similar: all joint/marginal probabilities appear in the fraction, those of an even number of variables in the numerator, and those of an odd number of variables in the denominator.  Multivariate mutual information is symmetric in all its arguments, but unlike the mutual information of two random variables, it can be positive, negative, or zero.  Apparently no one knows what it really means, though.

Comment: The 'meaning' is 'how much additional correlation is there in $x,y,z$ beyond the pair-wise correlations.'  A canonical example might be x={sunny,cloudy}, y={raining, not raining} and z={lawn is wet, not wet} and then consider sprinklered lawns and rare sun-showers.

Answer (score 4):

The general concept is called [multivariate mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information), but I believe that hardly anybody knows what it actually means and how it can be used. Note that the multivariate mutual information can become negative. For three variables it is defined as

$$I(X;Y;Z)=I(X;Y)-I(X;Y|Z)$$

where $I(X;Y|Z)$ is the [conditional mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information) of $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$.

Comment: If nobody knows what it means, how was it defined? Based just on a seemingly logical extension of mutual information? Do you know if there is any other meaningful definition? @leonbloy I wonder why wasn't just called  "multivariate information", or "multivariate shared information". For me the word "mutual" involves two things which is clearly not the case here.

Comment: Dictionaries pretty frequently define “mutual” as between two _or more_ parties. And yes, it was defined by analogy to the others.