# Definition of (codtitional) multivariate mutual information

Tags: information-theory

Mutual information (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information)) is defined as

$I(X_1;X_2) = \mathbb{E}\left[\log \frac{p(X,Y)}{p(X)p(Y)}\right]$,
which can be in the case of descrete random variables $X$ and $Y$  "simplified" to

$$\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)\log \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}\quad\quad (a)$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information) also says that the multivariate mutual information (MMI) is defined as

$$I(X_1;\ldots;X_{n}) = I(X_1;\ldots;X_{n -1}) - I(X_1;\ldots;X_{n - 1}|X_{n})$$

where 
$I(X_1;\ldots;X_{n-1}|X_{n}) = \mathbb E_{X_{n}}\big(I(X_1;\ldots;X_{n - 1})|X_{n}\big)\text{.}$

For $n = 3$, the situation is clear to me, since my intuition of what $\mathbb E_{X_{n}}\big(I(X_1;\ldots;X_{n - 1})|X_{n}\big)$ should be (simply condition all probabilities in $(a)$), agrees with the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information#Definition):

$$I(X_1;X_2|X_3) = \mathbb E_{X_3} \big(I(X_1;X_2)|X_3\big)
    = \sum_{x_3} p(x_3) \sum_{x_2} \sum_{x_1}
      p(x_1,x_2|x_3) \log \frac{p(x_1,x_2|x_3)}{p(x_1|x_3)p(x_2|x_3)}\text{.}$$

Moreover, in the case of $n = 3$, the MMI can be expressed by the "inclusion-exclusion principle" sum
$$I(X_1;X_2;X_3) = \sum_{I \subseteq \{1,2,\dots ,n\}} (-1)^{|I| + 1}H(X_I)\text{,}$$
where $H(X_I)$ is the entropy of the vector of the variables $X_i$, for which $i\in I$.

---

For $n= 4$, I would say that

$I(X_1;X_2;X_3|X_4) = \sum_{x_4}p(x_4)\sum_{x_3} p(x_3|x_4)\sum_{x_2}\sum_{x_1} p(x_1,x_2|x_3,x_4)\log\frac{p(x_1,x_2|x_3,x_4)}{p(x_1|x_3,x_4)p(x_2|x_3,x_4)}$,
but in this case, the upper "inclusion-exclusion principle sum" does not hold, since some terms are missing. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1205389/73561) to a similar question offers a nice suggestion for the definition of MMI, but there are two problems:

- The answer lacks a motivation for the definition.
- Only for odd $n$s, the definition is in concordance with the fact that MMI should equal $$\sum_{I \subseteq \{1,2,\dots ,n\}} (-1)^{|I| + n}H(X_I){.}$$

> Can you give me an explicit formula for conditional MMI for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ or at least for $I(X_1;X_2;X_3|X_4)$ (and motivation for it)?

From here, I will be probably able to find the defintion of MMI itself.

Comment: I am not really sure, why labelling the equation $(a)$ by \tag{a}\label{MI} works only in the case, when I am editing the question. Otherwise, only plain text `\sum_{x, y} p(x, y) ...` is visible.

Comment: You've made an error - The expression you write for $I(X_1;X_2;X_3\mid X_4)$ is actually equal to $ I(X_1;X_2 \mid X_3 ,X_4) $. This is because you've simply taken an extra expectation over the expression for $I(X_1;X_2\mid X_3)$ instead of first working out what $I(X_1;X_2;X_3)$ is. A simple way to see that the expression is incorrect is to note that it's not symmetric in $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$, which the 'MMI' is designed to be.

Comment: NB - if you want motivations, the above arise naturally in Marton's inner bound for the rate region of the $n$ to $1$ (discrete memoryless) broadcast channel.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Can you give some appropriate links or maybe a complete answer, please?

Comment: Added an answer, do ask me if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the shorthand $p_i$ for $p(x_i)$ as you've used in the question. Sums below are over the set $\mathcal{X}_1\times \mathcal{X}_2 \times \mathcal{X}_3 \times \mathcal{X}_4$, and it's tacitly assumed that all of these are finite sets.

\begin{align*}I(X_1;X_2;X_3|X_4) &= I(X_1;X_2|X_4) - I(X_1;X_2|X_3X_4) \\ &= \sum p_{1234} \log \frac{p_{12|4}}{p_{1|4} p_{2|4}} - \sum p_{1234} \log \frac{p_{12|34}}{p_{1|34} p_{2|34}} \\&= \sum p_{1234} \log \frac{p_{12|4} p_{1|34} p_{2|34}}{p_{1|4}p_{2|4}p_{12|34}},\end{align*}

where the first equality is by definition, and the rest are manipulation. But $p_{1|34}p_{3|4} = p_{13|4}$ by Bayes' rule.   We thus have $$I(X_1;X_2;X_3|X_4) = \sum p_{1234} \log \frac{p_{12|4}p_{13|4}p_{23|4}}{p_{1|4}p_{2|4}p_{3|4}^2 p_{12|34}} = \sum p_{1234} \log \frac{p_{12|4}p_{23|4}p_{13|4}}{p_{1|4}p_{2|4}p_{3|4} p_{123|4}}$$

which is a nice expression since it shows the symmetry of the functional explicitly. Now note that the expression you've written is actually $I(X_1;X_2|X_3X_4)$, and not $I(X_1;X_2;X_3|X_4)$.

Working further from this, you should be able to show that $$I(X_1;X_2;X_3;X_4) = \sum p_{1234} \log \frac{p_{12}p_{13}p_{14}p_{23}p_{24}p_{34} \cdot p_{1234}}{p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 \cdot p_{123} p_{124} p_{134} p_{234}}$$

(the dots are the usual products and are only put in for clarity). From here the inclusion-exclusion expression in terms of entropies of subsets is obvious. Indeed, it's possible to show the same inductively for every $n$-fold expression.(try it!).

---

One operational meaning for the expression $I(X_1;X_2:\dots; X_k)$ is in the achievability region for the $k$-user broadcast channel determined by the coding scheme due to Marton. Check out ch. 8(?) in the book by El-Gamal & Kim. (NB - there may well be other motivations for the same, this is just the one I happen to know)

Comment: Thanks, your derivation is clear. Will try to find the book.

Comment: Oh, and if in general you want to learn/work in network information theory, it's a great book to have a physical copy of, and usually runs ~$50 second hand.

Comment: I have read the instructions and you can delete them:)